# Convert an input array into a Google chart JS?

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to convert an input to an array which i need to us to display a Google Chart

The input array I got looks like,

```
$inputArray = [
    ['date' => '2016-12-10', 'code' => 'P'],
    ['date' => '2016-12-15', 'code' => 'P'],
    ['date' => '2017-02-10', 'code' => 'P'],
    ['date' => '2017-02-14', 'code' => 'P'],
    ['date' => '2017-03-10', 'code' => 'P'],
    ['date' => '2017-03-05', 'code' => 'U'],
    ['date' => '2017-03-11', 'code' => 'U'],
    ['date' => '2017-03-12', 'code' => 'P'],
    ['date' => '2017-04-07', 'code' => 'T'],
    ['date' => '2017-04-18', 'code' => 'P'],
    ['date' => '2017-04-19', 'code' => 'T'],
    ['date' => '2017-07-10', 'code' => 'P'],
];
```

Now I need to group by year and month and sum the code value (4 different values). For these I use a loop like so

```
function readPerMonth($tmpArray) {
    if (empty($tmpArray)) {
        $output[$year][$month] = ['P' => 0, 'T' => 0, 'U' => 0, 'E' => 0];
    } else {
        $output = [];
        foreach ($tmpArray as $value) {
            $year = date('Y', strtotime($value['date']));
            $month = date('M', strtotime($value['date']));

            if (empty($output[$year][$month]))
                $output[$year][$month] = ['P' => 0, 'T' => 0, 'U' => 0, 'E' => 0];
            // Check for incident intensity
            $output[$year][$month][$value['code']] += 1;
        }
    }

    ksort($output);
    ksort($output[$year][$month]);

    return $output;
}
```

and this gives me the Following output, hence last array is in another order???

```
Array
(
    [2017] => Array
        (
            [Feb] => Array
                (
                    [P] => 11
                    [T] => 0
                    [U] => 0
                    [E] => 0
                )

            [Mar] => Array
                (
                    [P] => 20
                    [T] => 0
                    [U] => 0
                    [E] => 0
                )

            [Apr] => Array
                (
                    [P] => 12
                    [T] => 0
                    [U] => 0
                    [E] => 0
                )

            [May] => Array
                (
                    [P] => 21
                    [T] => 0
                    [U] => 0
                    [E] => 0
                )

            [Jun] => Array
                (
                    [E] => 0
                    [P] => 7
                    [T] => 0
                    [U] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

and I this is an input Array which i need to convert in this JS to plot a stacked Google chart

```
$output = [
    ['2016-dec', 2, 0, 0, 0,'2'],
    ['2017-feb', 2, 0, 0, 0, '2'],
    ['2017-mar', 2, 0, 2, 0,'4'],
    ['2017-apr', 1, 1, 0, 0,'2'],
    ['2017-may', 1, 0, 0, 0, '1'],
];
```

My php function looks like this

```
function phpToJS($inputPHP) {
        $return = '';
        foreach ($inputPHP as $year => $months) {
            foreach ($months as $monthValue => $codeValues) {
                $sum = 0;
                $return .= "['" . $year . " - " . $monthValue . "', ";
                foreach ($codeValues as $key => $code) {
                    if ($key == '') { 
                        $return .= $code;
                    } else {
                        $return .= $code . ',';
                    }
                    $sum += $code;
                }

                $return .= ",'" . $sum . "'],";
            }
        }
        return $return;
    }
$tmpArr =  readPerMonth($inputArray);
$output = phpToJS($tmpArr);
```

but because of the last Array which isn't in the right order the Google Chart displays wrong.

ps: so sorry to have hit send and not finishing my question title :/

Comment: Convert input array into ***A*** ? What is `a`?

Comment: An `a` tag? A dangling subject line? A lost in thought?

Comment: I suppose `a`rray of another format.

Comment: u_mulder you help me out yesterday (and probably tomorrow ;)) Really appreciate the xtra explanation