# Looping through an array which has multiple arrays and last array is not in the same order?

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I am getting the following array from another php function, hence the last array is not in the same order as the rest:

```
Array
    (
        [2017] => Array
            (
                [Feb] => Array
                    (
                        [P] => 11
                        [T] => 0
                        [U] => 0
                        [E] => 0
                    )

                [Mar] => Array
                    (
                        [P] => 20
                        [T] => 0
                        [U] => 0
                        [E] => 0
                    )

                [Apr] => Array
                    (
                        [P] => 12
                        [T] => 0
                        [U] => 0
                        [E] => 0
                    )

                [May] => Array
                    (
                        [P] => 21
                        [T] => 0
                        [U] => 0
                        [E] => 0
                    )

                [Jun] => Array
                    (
                        [E] => 0
                        [P] => 7
                        [T] => 0
                        [U] => 1
                    )

            )

    )
```

To convert this php array data to a JS datasource I came up  with the following php function

```
   function phpToJS($inputPHP) {
            $return = '';
            foreach ($inputPHP as $year => $months) {
                foreach ($months as $monthValue => $codeValues) {
                    $sum = 0;
                    $return .= "['" . $year . " - " . $monthValue . "', ";
                    foreach ($codeValues as $key => $code) {
                        if ($key == '') { 
                            $return .= $code;
                        } else {
                            $return .= $code . ',';
                        }
                        $sum += $code;
                    }

                    $return .= ",'" . $sum . "'],";
                }
            }


return $return;
    }
```

it almost works except for the last array. Because of the wrong order, it doesn't seem to look at the key "names" just the position, so the output looks like

```
 ['2017 - Feb', 11,0,0,0,'11'],
['2017 - Mar', 20,0,0,0,'20'],
['2017 - Apr', 12,0,0,0,'12'],
['2017 - May', 21,0,0,0,'21'],
['2017 - Jun', 0,7,0,1,'8'] <---wrong ['2017 - Jun', 7,0,1,0,'8']
```

So how can i be sure the right sum numbers are at the right position?

Comment: Is it always going to be `P`, `T`, `U`, and then `E`? Then just access those keys directly instead of iterating over `$codeValues`.

Comment: And encoding to json __must be__ done with `json_encode`

Comment: Also, why is last array not the same?

Comment: And __also__ - what is the difference with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48241343/convert-an-input-array-into-a-google-chart-js?

Comment: Reading all your questions your error is in string `ksort($output[$year][$month]);`.

Comment: @u_mulder sorry i read in the docs that  json is not the format google Charts expects, so i merely output the row part used for a google chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$data = Array(2017 => Array(
                'Feb' => Array(
                        'P' => 11,
                        'T' => 0,
                        'U' => 0,
                        'E' => 0
                    ),
                'Mar' => Array
                    (
                        'P' => 20,
                        'T' => 0,
                        'U' => 0,
                        'E' => 0,
                    ),
                'Apr' => Array
                    (
                        'P' => 12,
                        'T' => 0,
                        'U' => 0,
                        'E' => 0,
                    ),
                'May' => Array
                    (
                        'P' => 21,
                        'T' => 0,
                        'U' => 0,
                        'E' => 0,
                    ),
                'Jun' => Array
                    (
                        'E' => 0,
                        'P' => 7,
                        'T' => 0,
                        'U' => 1,
                    ),
            )

    );
function reOrder($codeValues) {
    return Array(
        'P' => $codeValues['P'],
        'T' => $codeValues['T'],
        'U' => $codeValues['U'],
        'E' => $codeValues['E'],
    );
}
function phpToJS($inputPHP) {
            $return = '';
            foreach ($inputPHP as $year => $months) {
                foreach ($months as $monthValue => $codeValues) {
                    $sum = 0;
                    $return .= "'" . $year . " - " . $monthValue . "', ";
                    $codeValues=reOrder($codeValues);
                    foreach ($codeValues as $key => $code) {
                        if ($key == '') { 
                            $return .= $code;
                        } else {
                            $return .= $code . ',';
                        }
                        $sum += $code;
                    }

                    $return .= ",'" . $sum . "',";
                }
            }


return $return;
}
echo phpToJS($data);
?>
```

Try This.

Answer (score 1):

First thing. If you know about input and output keys order and it's not a huge work you can manually make it. For example

```
public function orderMonth(array $month)
{
    return [
        'P' => $month['P'],
        'T' => $month['T'],
        'U' => $month['U'],
        'E' => $month['E'],
    ];
}

$month = orderMonth($month);
```

The second note. Triple nesting loops looks very bad. The best pracises says that using even 2 nesting level it's not a good thing, so you should avoid it. So you can clean your code by using native php functions such as `array_sum` or `implode`.

```
foreach ($months as $month) {
    $sum = array_sum($month);
    $monthString = implode(',', array_merge($month, [$sum]));
    // other code
}
```

And finally. As I understood from the name of your function name you want to convert to JSON. For this you can using `json_encode` function instead of create your own bike :) Or what do you want to do?

Comment: tx, for your orderMonth function. Which I need to use before I put it as an inputArray, right? About your 2nd suggestion I am not quit sure how to incorporate it into my phpToJS function. This is what I need in the end,
 see arrayToDataTable part [link](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#stacked-bar-charts)

Answer (score 0):

You can sort array $months by keys. Add 
`ksort($months);`
before foreach $months